# jstz time zone in Rails does not seem to update if user changes system timezone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an implemenation of http://thisbythem.com/blog/clientside-timezone-detection/. Here are the key files/code:

## app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
around_filter :set_timezone
...
private

  def set_timezone
    if(current_learner)
      timezone = Time.zone = current_learner.time_zone
    else
      timezone = Time.find_zone(cookies[:timezone])
    end
    Time.use_zone(timezone) { yield }
  end
```

## app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('#flash_notification').hide().delay(500).slideDown('slow', function() {
      $(this).delay(4000).fadeOut();
   });
   $("#flash_notification").live('click', function(){
       $(this).stop().fadeOut();;
   });
});
//set event times for non-auth users
var tz = jstz.determine();
$.cookie('timezone', tz.name(), { path: '/' });
</script>
```

In addition to above added jquery.cookie.js & jstz.main.js to app/assets/js. The timezone cookie is set correctly upon first visiting the site, however if I change the system timezone, and refresh, I don't see the change in the cookie. Additionally, if I got to the js console and do:

```
tz=jstz.determine();
tz.name();
```

...I am not seeing the updated timezone setting here either. At the same time, if I delete cookies and refresh, then I DO get the new timezone.

Comment: Can you try moving js code setting cookie `var tz = jstz.determine();
$.cookie('timezone', tz.name(), { path: '/' });` inside `$(function() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out of I was using the jstz file. I had pulled down jstz.main.js instead of jstz.js For reference here is what you will need:

https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/src/823d744c9757481f0e33a6fea462514aa05fb30a/dist/jstz.js